# Over what range will integer arithmetic addition and subtraction be accurate to the integer in IEEE double precision floating point?

Tags: floating-point

According to [Wikipedia on the IEEE 64-bit floating point standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> Between 2<sup>52</sup>=4,503,599,627,370,496 and 2<sup>53</sup>=9,007,199,254,740,992 the
>   representable numbers are exactly the integers. For the next range,
>   from 2<sup>53</sup> to 2<sup>54</sup>, everything is multiplied by 2, so the representable
>   numbers are the even ones, etc.

Does this mean contiguous integers can be represented up to 2<sup>53</sup>?

In short I am trying to find the range of integer values upon which integer addition and subtraction operations will result in an exactly correct result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all integers from -2<sup>53</sup> to +2<sup>53</sup>, inclusive, are representable in IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point. An implementation that conforms to IEEE 754 will return exactly correct results for all operations `a+b` and `a-b` where `a`, `b`, and the mathematical result are integers in that interval.

Obviously, some results will be outside that interval, such as 2<sup>53</sup>+1, so many operations that produce such results will produce a value that is not exact due to rounding to a representable value.

An interval such that `a` and `b` being integers in the interval guarantees that `a+b` and `a-b` are exact is -2<sup>52</sup> to +2<sup>52</sup>, inclusive.

Comment: When entering `2e53-5` into Chrome (or Node.js), it is not expanded to the value accurate to the integer. So this must simply be a representation choice (rather than an indication of inaccuracy)? I also note that in Chrome `2e53-5 === 2e53` === true.

Comment: @Ben: `2e53` is not 2 to the power of 53. It is 2 times 10 to the power of 53, so it is 2*10**53, which is outside the interval where all integers are representable. 2e53-5 is not representable.

Comment: 2e53 is 2x10^53, not (conceptually) 1 << 52.

Comment: So how should I write 2^53 in a C-like-syntax language (like JavaScript)?

Comment: 2^53 in JavaScript is Math.pow(2, 53)

Comment: @Ben: JavaScript does not provide a good way to specify such values in floating point. C has a hexadecimal floating-point notation, in which 2**53 would be `0x1p53`. In JavaScript, you can use `Math.pow(2, 53)`, but `pow` is a difficult function to implement, and I would not rely on an implementation calculating `Math.pow(2, 53)` correctly, although a good implementation should. To be sure, you could prepare 2**53 as `(1<<26)*(1<<27)`.

Comment: OK thanks. Why does `1<<52` not "work" (i.e. give me 2^53) in JavaScript?

Comment: @Eric thank you very much for your patience in helping with this question.

Comment: @Ben: In JavaScript, the bitwise operators like `<<` operate on only 32-bit integers. JavaScript is not designed to be a language with strong typing. It has a flexible Number format that includes both some floating-point and some integer semantics. In a `<<` operation, the left operand is converted from a general Number to a 32-bit integer, then the shift is performed in a 32-bit integer format.

Comment: @Eric how have you developed such a deep understanding of various languages (including JS). Is it length of time, or continual reading or something else?

Comment: @Ben: I have been programming for over a third of a century, went to school for it, have had some challenging jobs, and occasionally get schooled answering a StackOverflow question incorrectly. Reading helps, particularly understand that theory comes from textbooks and academic papers, and authoritative knowledge comes from official standards (e.g., JavaScript should follow the [ECMA-262 Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) and documentation for software produced by the software producer, not from third-party web pages.

Comment: You can build up a number like 2<<53 by repeated multiplication by 2 instead of shifting.